# Groovy's @CompileStatic and map constructors

Tags: groovy

I'm using `@CompileStatic` for the first time, and confused as to how Groovy's map constructors work in this situation.

```
@CompileStatic
class SomeClass {
    Long id
    String name

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map map = new HashMap()
        map.put("id", 123L)
        map.put("name", "test file")
        SomeClass someClass1 = new SomeClass(map) // Does not work
        SomeClass someClass2 = map as SomeClass   // Works
    }
}
```

Given the code above I see the following error when trying to compile

`Groovyc: Target constructor for constructor call expression hasn't been set`

If `@CompileStatic` is removed, both constructors work properly.

Can anyone explain why `new SomeClass(map)` does not compile with `@CompileStatic`? And a possible addition, why does `map as SomeClass` still work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [`CompileStatic`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#compilestatic-annotation) documentation says:

> will actually make sure that the methods which are inferred as being
>   called ***will effectively be called at runtime***. This annotation turns
>   the Groovy compiler into a static compiler, where all method calls are
>   resolved at compile time and the generated bytecode makes sure that
>   this happens

As a result, a constructor with a Map argument is searched in the static compilation to "*resolve it at compile time*", but it is not found and thereby there is a compilation error:

```
Target constructor for constructor call expression hasn't been set
```

Adding such a constructor solves the issue with the `@CompileStatic` annotation, since it is resolved at compile time:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class SomeClass {
    Long id
    String name

    SomeClass(Map m) {
        id = m.id as Long
        name = m.name as String
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map map = new HashMap()
        map.put("id", 123L)
        map.put("name", "test file")
        SomeClass someClass1 = new SomeClass(map) // Now it works also
        SomeClass someClass2 = map as SomeClass   // Works
    }
}
```

You can check [`StaticCompilationVisitor`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/transform/sc/StaticCompilationVisitor.java) if you want to dig deeper.

Regarding the line

```
SomeClass someClass2 = map as SomeClass
```

You are using there the [`asType()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#asType(java.lang.Class)) method of [Groovy's GDK `java.util.Map`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html(java.lang.Class)), so it is therefore solved at runtime even in static compilation:

> Coerces this map to the given type, using the map's keys as the public
>   method names, and values as the implementation. Typically the value
>   would be a closure which behaves like the method implementation.

Answer (score 7):

Groovy actually does **not** give you a "Map-Constructor".  The constructors
in your class are what you write down.  If there are none (like in your case),
then there is the default c'tor.

But what happens, if you use the so called map c'tor (or rather call it
"object construction by map")?  The general approach of groovy is like this:

- create a new object using the default c'tor (this is the reason, why the
  construction-by-map no longer works, if there would be just e.g.
  `SomeClass(Long id, String name)`)
- then use the passed down map and apply all values to the properties.

If you disassmble your code (with `@CompileDynamic` (the default)) you see, that
the construction is handled by `CallSite.callConstructor(Object,Object)`,
which boils down to this this [code area](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/4993b10737881b2491c2daa01526fb15dd889ac5/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/ConstructorSite.java).

Now bring in the version of this construction by map, that is more familiar
for the regular groovyist: 
`SomeClass someClass3 = new SomeClass(id: 42L, name: "Douglas")`.

With the dynamic version of the code, the disassembly of this looks actually
alot like your code with the map.  Groovy creates a map from the param(s) and
sends it off to `callConstructor` - so this is actually the same code path
taken (minus the implicit map creation).

For now ignore the "cast-case", as it is actually the same for both static and
dynamic: it will be sent to `ScriptBytecodeAdapter.asType` which basically
gives you the dynamic behaviour in any case.

Now the `@CompileStatic` case:  As you have witnessed, your call with an
explicit map for the c'tor no longer works.  This is due to the fact, that
there never was an explicit "map-c'tor" in the first place.  The class still
only has its default c'tor and with static compilation `groovyc` now can just
work with the things that are there (or not if there aren't in this case).

What about `new SomeClass(id: 42L, name: "Douglas")` then?  This still works
with static compilation!  The reason for this is, that `groovyc` unrolls this
for you.  As you can see, this simply boils down to `def o = new SomeClass();
o.setId(42); o.setName('Douglas')`:

```
new           #2  // class SomeClass
dup
invokespecial #53 // Method "<init>":()V
astore_2
ldc2_w        #54 // long 42l
dup2
lstore_3
aload_2
lload_3
invokestatic  #45 // Method java/lang/Long.valueOf:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
invokevirtual #59 // Method setId:(Ljava/lang/Long;)V
aconst_null
pop
pop2
ldc           #61 // String Douglas
dup
astore        5
aload_2
aload         5
invokevirtual #65 // Method setName:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Comment: Better answer than the accepted one, methinks.  Thanks.